# Project vector to screenSpace

Tags: opengl

I have a right vector (glm::vec3 - called right) and a valid projection matrix P (glm::mat4)
I now need the right vector in screenspace. And here is where the confusion starts. 
My GLSL shaders uniforms for the vector is a vec2. I thought I would calculate the screenSpaceRightVector in C++ using glm with this little line of code:

```
glm::vec4 screenSpaceRightVector = (camData->P * glm::vec4(camData->right,0.0f));
```

and upload it to the shader with this line:

```
glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "screenSpaceRightVector"), screenSpaceRightVector.x, screenSpaceRightVector.y);
```

In my case the right vector is the xaxis of a camera coordinate system.

Is my computation for the screenSpaceRightVector correct?

Comment: Remember that when calculating the matrix, its always ModelMat * ViewMat * ProjMat * Point, so if you go by this, because you are not multiplying by any other matrices, this would indeed be your correct screen coordinates. If you add world and view transformations though, things would get slightly weirder because things might not actually be on screen, and then you would need to unproject your point to get its coordinates then multiply that point by your projection matrix. As far as I know, I have done this previously, though, I might be wrong, which is why im only putting this in a comment.

Comment: Out of interest, what do you need the screen coordinates for? Knowing this might make the question slightly easier to answer as well.

Comment: If this is really the right vector, its projection is simply a multiple of `(1, 0)`. Your transformation is missing the camera transform.

Comment: I need to reimplement this paper: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kopf/gdibr/index.html 
They use the screenSpaceRight vector for calculating the gradient images.

Comment: When expanding a `vec3` to a `vec4`, the 4th component (`w`) needs to be 1.0, not 0.0.